# How to show Firebase remote config in a ViewController

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, firebase-remote-config

I'm trying to show remote config but I don't know what to do in the view

I have a model:

```
struct PromoPill: Codable {

let imageUrl: String?
let imageWidth: Int?
let imageHeight: Int?
let targetUrl: String?
let enabled: Bool?
let position: Int?
```

And a manager that has a function that collects the json data

```
extension PromoPillManager : PromoPillGetDataProtocol {


func getItemFromRemoteConfig() -> PromoPill? {
    var promopill: PromoPill? = nil
    let jsonString = RemoteConfig.remoteConfig().configValue(forKey: RemoteConfigKey.promo_pill.rawValue).stringValue!
    do {
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        let jsonData = jsonString.data(using: .utf8)!
        let decodedPill = try decoder.decode(PromoPill.self, from:jsonData)
        promopill = decodedPill
    } catch {
        print(error)
        return nil
    }
    return promopill
}
```

I have never used remote config and I don't know how to call this manager from the view, if someone can help, I would appreciate it

At the ViewController I have this function which parses the data

```
    private func getActualPromoPill() -> PromoPill {
    var promoPill = PromoPill(imageUrl: nil, imageWidth: nil, imageHeight: nil, targetUrl: nil, enabled: nil, position: nil)
    if let promoPillDone = PromoPillManager.shared.getItemFromRemoteConfig(){
        promoPill = promoPillDone
        PromoPillManager.shared.saveStore(object: promoPill)
    }else{
        if let stored = PromoPillManager.shared.readStored(){
            promoPill = stored
        }else{
            return promoPill
        }
    }
    return promoPill
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you should register on the firebase console
https://console.firebase.google.com/

after you have defined your app and ...
you should define your key and value to RemoteConfig such as below pic:
[image: this pic]

you should configure your firebase to your project
pod:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/installation-methods?authuser=0#cocoapods

or swift package manager

https://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/installation-methods?authuser=0#swift-package-manager

after config and add the namespace you need.
you should use

https://firebase.google.com/docs/remote-config/get-started?platform=ios